# Generate a repeating sequence

Tags: r, sequence, repeat

I need to generate a vector of the following format using R:

```
1:10, 1:10, 11:20, 11:20, ... 121:130, 121:130
```

Is there an easier way than creating 12 vectors and then repeating each one twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
unlist(lapply(rep(seq(1, 121, by=10), each=2), function(x) seq(x, x+9)))
```

Answer (score 18):

Also you could do:

```
rep(1:10, 26) + rep(seq(0,120,10), each=20)
```

Comment: elegant! And given the number of ways to get to the result, I'm feeling a bit better about being flummoxed.

Comment: rats, came to this late and thought I had the fastest but this is so close to the optimal solution I'm just voting it up.  To make it even faster use "rep(0:12, each = 20)*10" after the + sign. (6x speedup overall)

Comment: further to the speed issue - this answer is 5x faster than lapply()).  The outer() answer below falls between this answer and my modification in performance. The newer matrix answer is about equal in speed to my modification here and perhaps the fastest overall.

Comment: And one more modification: `1:10 + rep(10*(0:12), each=20)`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
x <- matrix(1:130, 10, 13)
c(rbind(x, x))
```

---

Possible more efficient version:

```
x <- 1:130
dim(x) <- c(10,13)
c(rbind(x, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a combination of `rep` and `outer`, such as:

```
c(outer(1:10,rep(0:12,each=2),function(x,y)10*y+x))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do you.

```
x <- ((0:12)*10)+1
y <- x + 9

repeatVectors <- function(x,y){
    rep(seq(x,y),2)
}

z <- mapply(repeatVectors, x,y)
z <- as.vector(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

A method using `split` is

```
unlist(rep(split(seq_len(130), rep(1:13, each=10)), each=2), use.names=FALSE)
```