# Creating a repeating vector sequence in R

Tags: r, seq, rep

I need some help. How to create the following vector sequence:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

I tried to use (rep) and (seq) but still unsucessfull.

Comment: See these two also : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180125/repeating-a-repeated-sequence) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102777/r-generate-a-repeating-sequence)

Comment: @Sotos Here is a fun one for this particular problem: `sort(sequence(1:4))`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
rep(1:4,4:1)
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

or less concisely: `c(rep(1, 4), rep(2,3), rep(3, 2), 4)`

output: `[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4`